# Asset history in VersionOne

Tags: python, versionone

I am using the VersionOne Python SDK, and want to know when a Story moved into a certain project (Scope). I can retrieve the story but how do I get the history?

```
v1 = V1Meta()
for story in v1.Story.where(Number="S-01211"):
    print story.Scope.Name   # prints current value

# but how to retrieve historical values?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "asof" modifier if you have specific points in the past you'd like to see.  You'll have to include the scope name in the query "select" to get the historical value.

```
v1 = V1Meta()

past_date = '2012-11-01'

query = (v1.Story
           .where(Number="S-01211")
           .asof('2012-11-01')
           .select('Number', 'Name', 'Owners.Name', 'Scope.Name')
        )

for story in query:
    print story.data['Scope.Name']   # prints current value
```